# How can you handle DLL versions when referencing C++ DLL's over COM from VBScript with CreateObject?

Tags: c++, vbscript, com

We are using a software that mandates the use of VBS, but our analysis libraries are written in C++, so I've created a C++ DLL that abstracts the analysis libraries and passes them over a COM interface so that I can access these functions in VBS using `CreateObject`.

I have an installer that creates a directory in ProgramFiles to store the relevant DLL files, and then it uses RegAsm.exe to register this directory for COM use.

It is currently functioning properly, which is good, but leads to the following question: **If two VBS scripts require two different versions of the DLL, how do I specify which version to access in VBS?**

CreateObject doesn't seem to have a way to specify the version of the DLL you want, so I'm not really sure where to go from here... What would be the proper way to handle this?

As of currently if someone wants to use an older VBS script, they have no choice but to run the corresponding old version of the installer to downgrade their DLL to the correct version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just decided to update the ProgID to contain the current version with each major build/release.

I'm not sure if this is considered good practice, but it seems like the only way to specify DLL version in VBScript.

Comment: What you did is a good way. MS does that all the time, for example `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0` progid.